# Basketball simulator keeps executing?

Tags: java

My friend tried asking this question earlier and wasn't specific enough, so I'll try being a bit more detailed. We're trying to make a basketball simulator between two players that keeps playing until one player has reached 21 points, and then stops. We got fairly far, and while the program runs, it continues executing, instead of ending at 21 points for one player, and keeps running until I believe the program crashes. Does anyone have any idea on what needs to be added to prevent the program from executing after 21 points for one of the two players? I will post the code below, and if you would like a screenshot of the output, I would be happy to provide one. Thank you! 
Code:

```
import com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.generic.IF_ACMPEQ;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class KobeVsLebron {
    //VARIABLES
    public Random randomGenerator;
    private static int kscore = 0;
    private static int lscore = 0;
    //declare scanner
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //main method
    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        System.out.println("\n          Welcome to Kobe vs Lebron Simulation");
        System.out.println("In this simulation you will have a choice to flip a coin.");
        System.out.println("Whatever the outcome of the flip is the starting players ball.");
        System.out.println("The simulation is based off of a long standing argument");
        System.out.println("      Kobe Bryant vs Lebron James in a game of 21.");
        MainMenu();
    }


     /*******************************************************************************/
                                    METHODS

    //Main Menu
    //PlayKobe
    //PlayLebron
    //LeaderBoard();
    //ReadFile();
    //WriteFile();
    //Win();

     private static void MainMenu(){
        char choice;
        do {
            System.out.println("\nTo the run the simulation flip the coin by choosing 'F', \nTo print the leaderboard enter 'L' \nTo quit enter 'Q'");
            choice = input.next().charAt(0);
            switch (choice) {
                case 'F':
                case 'f':
                    FlipCoin();
                    break;
                case 'L':
                case 'l':
                    // LeaderBoard();
                    break;
                case 'Q':
                case 'q':
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid Choice! TRY AGAIN!");
            }
        }
        while (choice != 'Q');
    }

    private static void FlipCoin() {
        Random randomGenerator;
        int sides;
        int currentsides;
        System.out.printf("\nThe coin will be flipped heads(Kobe) or tails(Lebron)");
        randomGenerator = new Random(); //initialize random object
        sides = 2; //default number of sides
        currentsides =  randomGenerator.nextInt(sides)+1; //initialize roll (1-2)
        System.out.printf("\nThe coin is being flipped.....");
        //TIME DELAY '1000 is one second'
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1500);
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        if(currentsides == 1 ){
            System.out.printf("\nThe coin has been flipped to heads. \nKobe has the ball.");
            PlayKobe();
        }
        if(currentsides == 2){
            System.out.printf("\nThe coin has been flipped to tails. \nLebron has the ball.");
            PlayLebron();
        }
    }

    private static void PlayKobe() {
        Random randomGenerator;
        int shot;

        //int kscore = 0;
        int shotclock;

        if(kscore < 22){
            System.out.printf("\nKobe has won the game of 21!");
                //Win();
        }

        randomGenerator = new Random(); //initialize random object
        shot = 3; //default number of sides
        shotclock =  randomGenerator.nextInt(shot)+1; //initialize roll (1-2)

        if(shotclock == 1){
            System.out.printf("\nKobe drives in to the basket");
            System.out.printf("\nLebron on his tail!");
            System.out.printf("\nKobe scores the lay-up! and thats two for Kobe! ");
            kscore += 2;
            PlayLebron();
        }
        if(shotclock == 2){
            System.out.printf("\nKobe dribbles towards the line ");
            System.out.printf("\nLebron has him covered, Kobe takes the fade away shot!");
            System.out.printf("\nScore! thats 3 points for Kobe!");
            kscore += 3;
            PlayLebron();
        }
        if(shotclock == 3){
            System.out.printf("\nKobe is locked down and shaking!");
            System.out.printf("\nLebron Steals the ball! ");
            PlayLebron();
        }
    }

    private static void PlayLebron(){
        Random randomGenerator;
        int shot;
       // int lscore = 0;
        int shotclock;
        if(lscore < 22){

            System.out.printf("\nLerbon has won the game of 21!");
            //Win();
        }

        randomGenerator = new Random(); //initialize random object
        shot = 3; //default number of sides
        shotclock =  randomGenerator.nextInt(shot)+1; //initialize roll (1-2)

        if(shotclock == 1){
            System.out.printf("\nLebron drives in to the basket");
            System.out.printf("\nKobe on his tail!");
            System.out.printf("\nLebron scores the lay-up! and thats two for Lebron!");
            lscore += 2;
            PlayKobe();
        }
        if(shotclock == 2){
            System.out.printf("\nLebron dribbles towards the line ");
            System.out.printf("\nKobe has him covered, Lebron takes the fade away shot!");
            System.out.printf("\nScore! thats 3 points for Lebron!");
            lscore += 3;
            PlayKobe();
        }
        if(shotclock == 3){
            System.out.printf("\nLebron is locked down and shaking!");
            System.out.printf("\nKobe Steals the ball! ");
            PlayKobe();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The vast majority of your code is commented out.

Comment: Where you have `while (choice != 'Q');`, just check for score at the same time `while (choice != 'Q' && kscore < 21 && lscore < 21);`

Comment: I replaced that section with what you said, but I still seem to be getting the same error.

Comment: Maybe add brackets `while ((choice != 'Q') && (kscore < 21) && (lscore < 21));` but it should work.

Comment: Can you show us your output?

Comment: Still doesn't seem to be working, does it matter that this is a zip folder package, rather than the single class? That's the only other thing I can think of it being.

Comment: @Gerhard Yes. https://pastebin.com/xm2XLDrn

Comment: No it's my bad, I thought the program would check the loop every point but it doesn't. Just add a `return;` in places where you have `//Win()` in `PlayLebron()` and `PlayLebron()`. That will bring you back to the main loop.

Comment: Would you mind providing an example? I'm not that familiar with return statements and am not sure what to put.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you have

```
if(kscore < 22) {
    System.out.printf("\nKobe has won the game of 21!");
    //Win();
}
```

Which essentially means your code does nothing besides printing when a player reaches the score limit, you want to add a return statement to go back to your main loop.

You'll also want to check for when the score exceeds 21 and not the opposite.

```
if(kscore > 21) {
    System.out.printf("\nKobe has won the game of 21!");
    return;
}
```

You'll need that for both players ofc.

Comment: There are still a few problems in the code after that, for example the score is never reset, typing "q" in main loop does absolutely nothing and you have 2 methods that do the same thing with different names, when you could only have 1 and switch the names.